# 'rich' web apps with Clojure

Tags: web-applications, clojure, clojurescript

I am having a bit of a struggle while building a [Clojure](http://clojure.org) based web application. It's a simple CRUD app I started to explore the Clojure web ecosystem. I am experimenting with different libraries such as [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup), [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive), [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) and [Noir](http://www.webnoir.org/) (though Noir seems to be on the brink of deprecation).

My question is actually two questions. First is on the apparant lack of conventions for building clojure web apps. And secondly I need some hints on creating 'rich' html components.

What I love about the Clojure way is the ease of making different libraries play together. Replacing enlive with hiccup and the other way around is no big deal. Everything plays its single and simple role. Very much different from a complex framework like JSF.

But there is the point: This great freedom makes me feel a bit lost. In JSF I know where everthing has its place. I use Spring to integrate all components, Spring-Security to handle all session stuff. Component libraries relieve me from the stress of dealing with html, javascript and ajax issues.

Especially the aforementioned component libraries is what I am missing with Clojure. I found myself implementing things like a datatable with features like alternating row colors, pagination, column ordering, incremental filter and so on. And it leaves me with questions on how to synchronize browser and server state of such components especially when ajax is included. I was not able to find any mature answer on the net.

The advantage of frameworks: once you understood the rules and restrictions you can build your application and concentrate on the business rules. The technical infrastructure is dealt with and shouldn't be a distraction.

What suggestions are there for the Clojure world? Is [ClojureScript One](http://clojurescriptone.com/) a solution? I haven't yet looked into it. Does anyone know any component libraries that offer similar features like for example RichFaces datatable? Is there a preferred way of dealing with ajax?

---

Comment: This forum is not for discussion. It's for solving a particular problem. Clojurescript dumps out Javascript for the browser side. For the back end Noir has just been deprecated in favor of Compojure.

Comment: I'm aware of this forum not being for discussion. But I don't expect the one 'right' answer though. But I will remove that last sentence. As I said, I have not really looked into 'clojurescript One'. I know what clojurescript is. 'Clojurescript One' seemed to me like a starting point to wrap everything up. But I maybe wrong and it is only a tutorial app for starting with clojurescript.

Answer (score 4):

All I can give you are some guidelines:

- exchange messages between client and server in JSON or EDF
- separate your GUI code from your state-management code on the client
- put your state-management code in crossover so you can test it outside the browser
- arrange for your client GUI code to be as independent of a particular library as possible, go for libraries with active communities and least dependencies

Comment: crossover is when you declare a path of your code to be copied by cljsbuild (lein plugin) from your Clojure source to your Clojurescript source, this is done with a line in your project.clj. I used in the sense of making that part of your code pure Clojure, with absolutely no Clojurescript dependencies, which makes it possible to test using your normal Clojure environment.

Comment: I would certainly love to have a look at a complete example with sources in [GitHub](http://github.com). Doable?